# error: Failed to parse qmlimportscanner output

Tags: qt, parsing, qml

I have a created a fresh QML quick application using Qt 5.3.2 on Mac. When I build it has 2 link errors.

> ```
> Failed to parse qmlimportscanner output.:-1: error: 
> [iphonesimulator-debug] Error 66
> ```

I have not even made any changes to default application, why do I get these errors and how can I fix it?

Comment: I came around this issue and right now I am not mac but I had to change the target platform to Mac OS rather iOS. That way I can still work on my application and deal with it later when changing target to IOS...maybe by that time it's been fixed.

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is pretty old, however, as I just encountered the same error and finally managed to solve it: Your Project Path must not contain spaces for qml quick projects on ios.

Please do not ask me how or why this is the case (as it clearly works for desktop or android deployment), but this was the issue for me. After moving the project to a different location (a folder that does not contain spaces) it would run qmake and deploy just fine.